# How to validate the selection menu using a loop

Tags: java, validation, loops

Can someone edit my code to make it loop the selection menu. If the choice is not one of the 5 options it will prompt the user to re-enter until it is a valid option. If possible an explanation would be helpful as well. Thanks

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShapeLoopValidation
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        chooseShape();
    }

    public static void chooseShape()
    {
        while (true){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Select a shape number to calculate area of that shape!");
            System.out.print("Circle = 1. \nRectangle = 2. \nTriangle = 3. \nExit = 4. \nINPUT : ");
            int shapeChoice = sc.nextInt();
            //while (true) {
            if (shapeChoice >= 1 && shapeChoice <=4)
            {
                if (shapeChoice == 1)
                {
                    circle();
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 2)
                {
                    rectangle();
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 3)
                {
                    triangle();
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 4)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Error : Choice " + shapeChoice + "Does not exist.");
            }
        }

        class Test {
            int a, b;

            Test(int a, int b) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: correct code indentation

Comment: "Can someone edit my code to make it loop the selection menu. If the choice is not one of the 5 options it will prompt the user to re-enter until it is a valid option." <- Your code already does that. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First: take a look at [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Second: read a bit about [do-while loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) (they are usually a good fit for this kind of situations).

Now, how I would implement it (but you should really learn how to make a loop in this scenarios):

```
public static void chooseShape () {

    boolean valid = false;
    do {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select a shape number to calculate area of that shape!");
        System.out.print("Circle = 1. \nRectangle = 2. \nTriangle = 3. \nExit = 4. \nINPUT : ");
        int shapeChoice = sc.nextInt();

        switch (shapeChoice) {
            valid = true;
            case 1:
                circle();
                break;
            case 2:
                rectangle();
                break;
            case 3:
                triangle();
                break;
            case 4:
                return;
            default:
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("Error : Choice " + shapeChoice + "Does not exist.");
                System.out.println("Please select one that exists.") 
        }
    } while (!valid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `do-while` flow control until EXIT code entered:

```
int shapeChoice;
do {
   System.out.println("Select a shape number to calculate area of that shape!");
   System.out.print("Circle = 1. \nRectangle = 2. \nTriangle = 3. \nExit = 4. \nINPUT : ");
   int shapeChoice = sc.nextInt();
   // then use if-else or switch   
} while (shapeChoice != 4);
```

**OR**

use `break` statement to loop break at your code as bellow:

```
else if (shapeChoice == 4)
{
   break;
}
```